# How to make "long tv_nsec" and "time_t tv_sec" compatible?

Tags: c, posix

I am writting a wrapper function `sleep_new()` for `clock_nanosleep()` which would make thread suspension easier for me.

```
// POSIX.1-2017 is what compiler is confined to.
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700

#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// POSIX headers.

// Other headers
#include "sleep_new.h"

void sleep_new(long value, const char unit[3]){
    
    // Create a timespec structure and set it's members.
    // Members are added together!!! So to set time "1.5 s" we set "t.tv_sec = 1" and "t.tv_sec = 500000000".
    // Members ".tv_sec" and ".tv_nsec" represent unit and not value!
    struct timespec sleep_time;

    // Set flags i.e. TIMER_ABSTIME to 0 to use relative instead of absolute time.
    int flags = 0;

    // Choose the clock i.e. CLOCK_MONOTONIC is a "clock_id" for the clock started at system start.
    int clock_id = CLOCK_MONOTONIC;

    // Set timespec structure's members according to the chosen unit.
    if (!strcmp(unit, "s")) {
        sleep_time.tv_sec = value;
        sleep_time.tv_nsec = 0;
    }
    else if (!strcmp(unit, "ns")){
        sleep_time.tv_sec = 0;
        sleep_time.tv_nsec = value;
    }
    else if (!strcmp(unit, "us")){
        sleep_time.tv_sec = 0;
        sleep_time.tv_nsec = value * 1000;
    }
    else if (!strcmp(unit, "ms")){
        sleep_time.tv_sec = 0;
        sleep_time.tv_nsec = value * 1000000;
    }
    else{
        puts("Unit not supported - choose between: s, ms, us, ns\n");
    }

    // Because last argument is NULL in case of error, remaining time is not stored in "t".
    clock_nanosleep(clock_id, flags, &sleep_time, NULL);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Counter.
    uint8_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        // Stdout is newline  buffered. This is why we either have to include `\n` at the end or flush() it manually.
        // So uncomment one example A or B.

        // A
        //printf("%d\n", i);

        // B
        printf("%d, ", i);
        fflush(stdout);

        // Because last argument is NULL in case of error, remaining time is not stored in "t".
        sleep_new(1000, "ms");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

If I call this function with `sleep_new(1, "s")` or `sleep_new(2, "s")` it works fine, because it sets the `sleep_time.tv_nsec = 0;` and `sleep_time.tv_sec = value;`.

In any other scenarios i.e. `sleep_new(1000, "ms")` something is wrong and sleep is not applied. I debugged application and values are applied to the `timespec` members just fine but `clock_nanosec()` just ignores them.

[image]

I am using type `long` for the `value` because I read in the POSIX [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) where header `time.h` defines `timespec` structure's members `tv_nsec` who needs `long` and member `tv_sec` who uses `time_t` which is in turn defined in header `sys/types.h` like this:

> `time_t` shall be an *integer type*.

So because `long` can also hold `int` values I expected this to work, but it doesn't. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tv_nsec` is the number of nanoseconds in a second - `1000 * 1000000` nanoseconds is too much. That's 1 second! `tv_nsec` should range from `0` to `999999999`. The proper calculation could look like:

```
    sleep_time.tv_sec = value / 1000;
    sleep_time.tv_nsec = (value % 1000) * 1000000;
```

Comment: Ah crap. I did not know that `tv_nsec` has an upper limit of `999999999`... I thought long has a range of `-9223372036854775808` to `922337203685477580`?

Comment: Type has (almost) nothing to do with interpretation. and `long` has the size of __at least__ 2^31...2^31 .

Comment: Can you explain why you used integer division and then modolo & multiplication?

Comment: I do not believe I can. If you have a number greater then `1000`, like `12345` milliseconds. How would _you_ extract from that number the number of seconds and nanoseconds? Take a sheet of paper and try to find out.